# gzip multiples directory into archives in another directory

Tags: gzip, archive

I want to back up each of the directories in `/home`, in separate `.tar.gz files`, to the `/backup` directory. Here an example. I know how to compress them. But not sure, how to send it in another directory.

```
/home/ab123456, /home/ertoto, /home/mange
```

```
/backup/ab123456.tar.gz, /backup/ertoto.tar.gz, /backup/mange.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the contents of `/home`

```
cd /home

for file in */; do tar czf /backup/"$file".tar.gz "$file";done
```

Comment: I would recommend changing the glob pattern to `*/` in the `for` loop to ensure that only _directories_ are zipped, not regular files ...

Comment: @AdminBee yes good idea, I added.

Comment: when i tried, i got this error ```tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: /backup/mange/.tar.gz : write impossible: Relais brisé (pipe)
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```